# I want to extract menu_header from bubble_list and then need to extract all titles from menu_list with condition type='menu' only

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-extraction

I want to extract menu_header from bubble_list and then need to extract all titles from menu_list with condition type='menu' only

```
response3 = [{"thumbs_id":56071,"disable_text":"yes","thumbs_display":"no","recipient_id":"12698","bubble_list":[{"class":"bubble-top","delay":0,"logo":"no","text":"You may only add\/change your preferred first name and legal last name in PIMS.","type":"text"},{"class":"bubble-menu","delay":3000,"logo":"yes","menu_header":"Which name would you like to update?","menu_list":[{"payload":"\/update_name{\"name_type\":\"preferred_first_name\"}","title":"Update Preferred First Name"},{"payload":"\/update_name{\"name_type\": \"legal_last_name\"}","title":"Update Legal Last Name"}],"menu_status":"always_active","type":"menu"}],"button_list":[{"payload":"\/inactivity_timeout","title":"End Chat"},{"payload":"\/bot_help{\"bot_help_value\":\"start_over\"}","title":"Start Fresh again"}],"related_question":[]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit long but it works:

```
response = {key:value for key, value in response3[0].items() if key == 'bubble_list'}
filter = [my_dict for my_dict in response['bubble_list'] if 'menu_header' in list(my_dict.keys()) and my_dict.get('type') == 'menu']
menu_header = filter[0]['menu_header']
menu_list = [title.get('title') for title in filter[0]['menu_list']]
```